# Using socket.io authorisation in https to update and lookup session, express 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, socket.io

I have set set my node.js server, using express 3.1.4 througth https. I am trying to update and lookup my session object (using sessionStore) directly with socket.io. I used extended exemple and explanation for the handshake authorisation process. But after is set the authorisation process, socket.io suddently stop to start connections.

I made research and tried many solution, including redis, mongoStore and session.socket.io, but i seem to always end up with socket not connecting, i am pretty sure its related to beeing in https.

Does anyone have an idea why this setup does not work ? If we get rid of io.set , socket suddently restart connecting ..

Thank you in advance !

```
var io      = require('socket.io'),
https    = require('https'),
express = require('express');

var path = require('path');  
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var fs = require('fs');
var passphrase = "";
var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('var/keys/server.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('var/keys/server.crt')
};


if(passphrase) {
    options.passphrase = passphrase;
}


// We define the key of the cookie containing the Express SID
 var EXPRESS_SID_KEY = 'express.sid';

// We define a secret string used to crypt the cookies sent by Express
var COOKIE_SECRET = 'some secret';
var cookieParser = express.cookieParser(COOKIE_SECRET);

// Create a new store in memory for the Express sessions
var sessionStore = new express.session.MemoryStore();

 var app = express();

 // Configure Express app with :
 // * Cookie Parser created above
 // * Configure Session Store
app.configure(function () {
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', { layout: false });
app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(express.session({
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: { 
        httpOnly: true
    },
    key: EXPRESS_SID_KEY
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use("/app", express.static(__dirname + "/app"));
});

 //passport config
 var Account = require('./models/account');
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
 passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
 passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

 //mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/passport_local_mongoose');

// Configture routes
 require('./routes')(app);

 // Create https server, register socket.io as listener
 server = https.createServer(options, app);
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
 console.log(("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port')));
 io = io.listen(server);

 // We configure the socket.io authorization handler (handshake)
 io.set('authorization', function (data, callback) {
  if(!data.headers.cookie) {
     return callback('No cookie transmitted.', false);
}


 cookieParser(data, {}, function(parseErr) {
 if(parseErr) { return callback('Error parsing cookies.', false); }

    // Get the SID cookie
    var sidCookie = (data.secureCookies && data.secureCookies[EXPRESS_SID_KEY]) ||
                    (data.signedCookies && data.signedCookies[EXPRESS_SID_KEY]) ||
                    (data.cookies && data.cookies[EXPRESS_SID_KEY]);

    // Then we just need to load the session from the Express Session Store
    sessionStore.load(sidCookie, function(err, session) {
        // And last, we check if the used has a valid session and if he is logged in
        if (err || !session || session.isLogged !== true) {
            callback('Not logged in.', false);
        } else {

            // You can access it later with "socket.handshake.session"
            data.session = session;

            callback(null, true);
        }
    });
 });
 });


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log("socket.io started on port"+ app.get('port'));

socket.on("request",function(data){
    console.log("socket answer = "+ data);
    socket.emit("response", [ "docA" ,"docB"]);
});
socket.on("save",function(data){
    console.log("socket save = "+ data);
   memory += data + " ";
    console.log("memory = "+ memory);   

});

});


server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well i found a solution to my problem. I still do not know why the socket handshake does not work properly in https. I decided to ude [connect-mongoose with MongoDb.](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose) It works perfectly in https and can be used outside of req res function call, as needed.

I also can use it along my socket.on, so it ruled out my problem.